# Installing gir1.2-gtk-3.0 on Centos

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, apt-get, centos8, dnf

On Ubuntu there is a package for installing **gir1.2-gtk-3.0**:

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

Centos 'dnf provides gir1*' results in error: No Matches found

The package can be found on https://github.com/roojs/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0, but there is no installation script, only files with extension *.gir

How can it be installed manually?

The installation is necessary to avoid:

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
Python: Namespace Gtk not available

Other packages gobject-introspection, python3-gi are alredy installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gir1.2-*` packages are for Debian and Debian-derived distributions.

The introspection data that is consumed by the Python bindings is provided by `typelib` files, for instance:

```
/usr/lib64/girepository-1.0/Gtk-3.0.typelib
```

These files are provided by the library package, on CentOS, alongside the actual shared library. For instance, the `Gtk-3.0.typelib` file is provided by the `gtk3` package.

The GIR files are XML descriptions of the API that are only used when generating the introspection data; they are provided by the `devel` package, on CentOS. For instance, the `Gtk-3.0.gir` file is provided by the `gtk3-devel` package.

If pygobject cannot find the `typelib` file, it's likely that you've installed it in some non-standard location. You must use the `GI_TYPELIB_PATH` environment variable to list all the locations where the typelib data might be found, as a colon-separated list of paths.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Indeed the typelib file was dispersed in two directories .../local/lib/girepository-1.0 and .../local/lib64/girepository-1.0